# java.lang.NumberFormatException in response

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting a NumberFormatException from my response and the data is an Int.

Could someone help me identify the issue?

Received error:

[image: received error]

Json response:

[image: jsonresponse]

Data class:

[image: data class]

Answer (score 1):

Max int value is 2147483647. Your id is bigger and longer than int. Try use long instead of int.